# Need some assistance with a complex JOIN is SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Take a look at these tables

[image]

It's simple: `Venue` contains **country_ID** which is an FK in `Society_Territory` where we will find a **society_ID** which is an FK of `Society`. I have a Venue_ID during the query and my ***objective*** is to get the **Society_Name** but there is a twist but first lets just get the **Society_Name**

In the following query only look at **JOINS** and in there I am gonna add comments with this `//` prefix

```
SELECT
    uuid()AS `UUID`,
    `pc`.`PRSClaimID` AS `prsclaimid`,      
    `a`.`LoginName` AS `loginname`,
    `a`.`BandName` AS `bandname`,
    `smartistdetails`.`LoginName` AS `createdbyloginname`,          
    `Society`.`Society_Name` AS societyName
    count(
        `smliveclaims`.`LiveclaimsID`
    )AS `gigcount`    

FROM `smprsliveclaimlink`

JOIN `smliveclaims` ON `smprsliveclaimlink`.`fkLiveClaimID` = `smliveclaims`.`LiveclaimsID`

// Here I have the Venue_ID from smliveclaims so i starting moving towards society name

JOIN Venue ON `smliveclaims`.fk_venueId = Venue.Venue_ID
JOIN Society_Territory ON Venue.Country_ID = Society_Territory.Country_ID
JOIN Society ON Society_Territory.Society_Id = Society.Society_ID    

// Now from Society i can select the Society_Name which i am already doing in the query above

JOIN `smartistdetails` `a`
JOIN `smprsclaims` `pc` ON `a`.`ArtistID` = `pc`.`fkArtistID`
JOIN `smcategories` ON `pc`.`FK_CategoryID` = `smcategories`.`Id`
JOIN `smcategoriestype` ON  `smcategories`.`fk_CategoryTypeId` = `smcategoriestype`.`Id`
JOIN `smartistdetails` ON `pc`.`CreatedBy` = `smartistdetails`.`ArtistID` AND `smprsliveclaimlink`.`fkPRSClaimID` = `pc`.`PRSClaimID`

GROUP BY
    `a`.`LoginName`,
    `a`.`BandName`,
    `smcategories`.`Id`,
    `smcategoriestype`.`CategoryType`,
    `smartistdetails`.`LoginName`
```

All is cool till here. Now here is the **TWIST**

I will have `Country_ID`s in `Venue` which will not be in `Society_Territory`. And I still want to select them and instead of showing and actual `Society_Name` want to show a word such as "Other"

Comment: Use a Left Join, will fetch all matched records, plus records on the Left and for those equivalent null on the right, here you can substitute by a select..case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a LEFT OUTER JOIN when you link VENUE with SOCIETY_TERRITORY and so on when you link SOCIETY_TERRITORY with SOCIETY

Pay attention: When you use a LEFT OUTER JOIN all tables depends by its must be linked with other LEFT OUTER JOIN because if you use INNER JOIN you cancel di effects on LEFT.

Edit:

```
SELECT
    uuid()AS `UUID`,
    `pc`.`PRSClaimID` AS `prsclaimid`,      
    `a`.`LoginName` AS `loginname`,
    `a`.`BandName` AS `bandname`,
    `smartistdetails`.`LoginName` AS `createdbyloginname`,          
    coalesce(`Society`.`Society_Name`, 'Other') AS societyName
    count(`smliveclaims`.`LiveclaimsID`)AS `gigcount`    
FROM `smprsliveclaimlink`
JOIN `smliveclaims`
    ON `smprsliveclaimlink`.`fkLiveClaimID` = `smliveclaims`.`LiveclaimsID`
// Here I have the Venue_ID from smliveclaims so i starting moving towards society name
JOIN Venue ON `smliveclaims`.fk_venueId = Venue.Venue_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Society_Territory ON Venue.Country_ID = Society_Territory.Country_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Society ON Society_Territory.Society_Id = Society.Society_ID    
// Now from Society i can select the Society_Name which i am already doing in the query above
JOIN `smartistdetails` `a`
JOIN `smprsclaims` `pc` ON `a`.`ArtistID` = `pc`.`fkArtistID`
JOIN `smcategories` ON `pc`.`FK_CategoryID` = `smcategories`.`Id`
JOIN `smcategoriestype` ON  `smcategories`.`fk_CategoryTypeId` = `smcategoriestype`.`Id`
JOIN `smartistdetails` ON `pc`.`CreatedBy` = `smartistdetails`.`ArtistID` AND `smprsliveclaimlink`.`fkPRSClaimID` = `pc`.`PRSClaimID`
GROUP BY
    `a`.`LoginName`,
    `a`.`BandName`,
    `smcategories`.`Id`,
    `smcategoriestype`.`CategoryType`,
    `smartistdetails`.`LoginName`
```

Comment: i am not familiar with `left outer join` or `inner join` for that matter a little more elaboration please

Comment: @JunaidSaeed: Joins are part of SQL basics, they aren't really something to be elaborated on here. Any SQL tutorial should cover them. Plenty of blog articles out there are dedicated to joins. Here's one to start with: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 0):

All your `JOIN`s are `INNER JOIN`s. The `INNER` keyword is optional in MySQL and frequently omitted (as in your example). Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` where required and amend your SELECT clause to include something like "COALESCE(Society_Name,'Other') Society_Name"